# Debconf window appearing after installing Burg

Tags: bootloader, burg, debconf

I have just added the PPA 'ppa:bean123ch/burg' with a view to installing Burg, a graphical boot manager. In the Software Center, after having clicked on 'Install' for burg-pc, I have a pop-up window titled 'debconf on *my computer name*', asking me to configure BURG.

It has to entry areas. One, which is blank, label as "Linux Command Line" and another, which already has "quiet splash" in it, is labeled as Linux default Command Line.

What should I do ? Should I choose the default, as suggested on [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1513509) on the Ubuntu Forums ?

Comment: I think I'll try, and give feedback about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely press **Ok** in that case

Answer (score 0):

Have a read through the documentation on the [BURG page here](http://code.google.com/p/burg/) it also links to a [community documentation page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Burg) that is quite useful for installation troubleshooting.

I know previously you need BUC installed but I'm not sure if this is still the case; see the [article here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/11/burg-boot-manager-tool-updated-1-0/) and the comment by 'charlie andrews'

Answer (score 0):

I think installing BURG enables you to change the boot screen of ubuntu.By doing this you can convert the older default themes in to animated themes.For more about BURG refer http://ubuntumanual.org/posts/257/burg-gorgeous-alternative-to-grub-add-icons-animated-menus-and-themes